# DC Barrel - Powering a battery pack

Tags: dc, battery-charging, plug

I am looking for a DC barrel to power a battery pack. The battery in question is connected in 10S3P, that's is a nominal voltage of 36V. I am currently looking for a DC barrel that can withstand at least 42V and currents up to 2A.

I have seen some companies that charge the battery pack using a RCA plugs, however would like to avoid using them because they are not design for that. I have check DC [plugs](https://www.cui.com/catalog/interconnect/connectors/dc-power-connectors/jacks?pg=2) but I can hardly find that can withstand 42V or higher. However, most of them are design for 24 volts.

I was wondering if I could use them as long as I maintain the power output within the safety threshold. Let's say that the dc plug has is designed to safely withstand 24V and 5 A. Could I used with 42 volts and 3 amperes. If not, what would be your advice?

Answer (score 0):

Digikey has numerous jacks rated for 48V, 5A.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-power-connectors/435?FV=ffe001b3%2C70017d&quantity=0&ColumnSort=-14&page=1&stock=1&k=barrel+jack&pageSize=25&pkeyword=barrel+jack

Go to www.digikey.com and search for"barrel jack", select "Barrel - power connectors" and then use the filters to narrow down the search: Active, In stock, male/female, voltage, amps, mounting style, etc.

Comment: While this provides an off-site list of applicable products, it could become out of date if the vendor changes the URL, etc. Consider providing information to the OP about _how_ to find satisfactory products, regardless of the specific vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be a "barrel" type jack, Anderson PowerPole (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_Powerpole) connectors would probably work quite well, as they're likely available locally, and provide the necessary isolation.

The (Anderson) suggested colour-code would be Blue (48VDC), and you can also then use the battery as both a power-source, and a power-sink (charge)